# Weird issue with ObservableCollection<T> on Windows Phone 8 / MVVM

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm, observablecollection

I'm looking for some help with a random problem I've come across when using ObservableCollection on my Windows Phone 8 project. I have some data saved in a SQLite database, and I'm populating this ObservableCollection with my read CRUD operation in my ViewModel's constructor so that the list is populated as soon as the app is opened. All this works fine as I want, but the weird issue that I'm getting is I keep getting the following error on my View where I set the DataContext to my ViewModel when I build/run the solution;

[image]

Like I said, even with this error, the list still shows with the data from the database. To narrow it down, I removed the code from my constructor and placed it inside a button and when the button is pressed, the data loads as before when it was in the constructor, there's no error like above when the solution is built/ran.

I'm confused over how to fix this because I'd rather have the data loaded as soon as the app is opened rather than having to tap a button. Am I creating the collection in my constructor wrong or something? Hopefully someone here can help me a bit. Here's some code to show what I'm doing;

In my ViewModel I'm creating my list like;

```
private ObservableCollection<SleepTrackerModel> _sleepHistory;
public ObservableCollection<SleepTrackerModel> SleepHistory
{
    get { return _sleepHistory; }
    set 
    {
        if (_sleepHistory != value)
            _sleepHistory = value;

        OnPropertyChanged("SleepHistory")
    }
}
```

And in my constructor I'm doing (which is causing the error in the picture);

```
public SleepTrackerViewModel()
{
    string read = "SELECT * FROM SleepTrackerModel ORDER BY SleepID ASC"
    SleepHistory = _dbHelper.Read<SleepTrackerModel>(read);
}
```

But when I put the exact same code in a button, there's no error, so it must be how I'm doing my code in the constructor that is wrong? At first I thought it might be my Read method in DBHelper, but I've tested it in the Debug, and it works as expected on the View regardless of this error.

Any help would be brilliant. Thanks.

EDIT:

Sorry, it doesn't work at all when I use the constructor to populate the ObservableCollection with data. I get that error and no data displays in the ObservableCollection. It only seems to work when I use a button with the select statement and Observable code in it, but I'd like the data to load as soon as that page is opened, so I need it to work in the constructor?

Comment: If you need to take a screenshot of something with a mouseover just press Ctrl + Print Screen on your keyboard while the mouse over is open, this will copy your screen to the clipboard. Then you can go to Paint and paste the image and crop it down to only the relevant part and post that image.

Comment: Better? Was using a picture I shared with someone earlier from my phone.

Comment: If you want the data to be loaded when you navigate to the the page, just use the OnNavigatedTo method and call you viewmodel method that basically load the needed data..

Comment: Side note--just expose your OC via a read-only property.  INPCing a property for an INCC collection is like an unsharpened pencil.

Comment: Loop, thanks for the suggestion. I'm going to use either the OnNavigatedTo method or implement a feature to select a month from a combo or flyout, then load the data that way.

Will, do you mean get rid of my get/set and just declare like; private readonly ObservableCollection<SleepTrackerModel> _sleepHistory; ?